# Ubuntu flashing screan on power off and turn on after suspend

Tags: dell, screen, flicker

I installed ubuntu 20.04 on my Dell Studio 1555 laptop and It flashes two or three times when I try to turn it off and when It woke up after suspend.
I had this problem with older versions of Ubuntu and even Kali linux

[image: Here you can see what happens]

Comment: If it works fine other than those 2 seconds then not really a problem or is it? Be glad that such old machine still works and have decent support with Linux.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Yes, but my laptop easily runs all Windows versions so my question came up as to why it should flashing in Linux

Comment: It has an old graphics that never had the "love" it deserved from the Linux AMD graphics drivers. Initially, and for a few years after, it was supported by proprietary drivers. Then AMD moved to make all their graphics drivers open-source and by that time this chip was already old. So, the family of drivers that has been used since that time focused mostly on newer chips.